# I want to give specific editing to specific h1 tag

Tags: html, css

Can I give specific formatting to an `h1` tag using CSS on specific portion of the page?

Like we use:

```
h1{                      

}
```

I want something like this:

```
.specific.h1{

}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you can add to your html classes, then yes. If you have `<h1 class="specific">HEADING</h1>` then the css to edit this is `h1.specific{your code here}`

Comment: Seems like you're a beginner in CSS: a [tutorial like WebPlatform](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css) may be a better place than StackOverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class (`.`) comes after the element. Same with an ID (`#`).

```
h1.specific {

}
h1#specific {

}
```

HTML Usage

```
<h1 class="specific"></h1>
<h1 id="specific"></h1>
```

**Edit:**

As Mentioned in the comments, you can also set classes and IDs by simply:

```
.specific {

}
#specific {

}
```

This means that anything with the `specific` class or ID will get the styling from it. (eg: `h1`, `p`, `a`).

Comment: Selecting an element via its class only, without writing down the element in front of the class, is a good practice: who knows if one day we won't want to style a certain h2, h3, p or li the same way? And there's no immediate consequence (just don't add a class you don't want to apply and don't use the same name for 2 different purposes)